# How to make a part of a JButton's name colored?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have JButton and I need to make only couple characters of its name to be colored, how can I do that?

Comment: Try using <HTML> text

Comment: Or create an Image, make an ImageIcon and give it the Icon.

Comment: Note that using HTML formatting in a button will interfere with the default disabled look of the button..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class SetJButtonTextColor
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        JButton button=new JButton();
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("Frame");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        button.setText("<html><span style=\"color:blue\">Click</span>   <span style=\"color:green\">Here</span></html>");
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200,100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

*Output*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
button.setText("<html>a<span style=\"color:red\">b</span>cde</html>")
```